# Mark the broken hyperlink in a column of MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access table with a hyperlink column.  In the form when clicking the hyperlink, it will open the linked site. If the link is broken, it will display automatically the message "unable to open------.  cannot open the specified file".  After clicking OK, I will put "no file" in another column.

My question is whether we can simplify the process:  when I click the OK, the 'no file' will be put in the another column automatically or  if the hyperlink is broken, the 'no file' will be put without the warning message.

Comment: Possibly in error handler code.

Answer (score 0):

As June7 said, we can use Error handler code to do this:

```
    Private Sub File_Link_Click()
       On Error GoTo ErrHandler

   ErrHandler:
    File_Link_Note.Value = "No file"
    On Error Resume Next
   End Sub
```